# C# SecureString Usage From COM DLL

Tags: c#, com

I'm trying to fix some Fortify errors.
A class in my code () stores the password in a string.

```
 public class Foo: IDisposable
 {
 public string Password
  {
     get;
     set;
  }
 }
```

Fortify recommended that I should change the string to SecureString.
That fixes the Fortify issue but after this I am unable to use this create the COM Object.

Comment: more info please, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Yeap and more details on how you try to create the COM object would likely help too.

Comment: I think you will need to convert the secureString into a normal string when calling the COM Dll. Or you would need to change the COM DLL as well to offer an additional call with SecureString instead of normal string.

Answer (score 0):

I would define the class like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class TestSecureString : IUnsecurePassword
{
    public SecureString Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    string IUnsecurePassword.Password
    {
        get
        {
            if (Password == null)
                return null;

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(Password);
            string bstr = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
            Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
            return bstr;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                Password = null;
                return;
            }

            Password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in value)
            {
                Password.AppendChar(c);
            }
        }
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IUnsecurePassword
{
    string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then in C++, the `IUnsecurePassword` interface would be exported like this:

```
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_Password (/*[out,retval]*/ BSTR * pRetVal ) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall put_Password (/*[in]*/ BSTR pRetVal ) = 0;
```

It does not prevent someone from using the IUnsecurePassword interface if he really wants to, but it raises the bar.